# Find all solutions of row reduced echelon matrix in pure python

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, linear-algebra

I have

```
toggle =    [[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
             [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

puzzle = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

`toggle` is a matrix I already transformed to [row echelon form] with Gaussian elimination. This is in [`GF(2)` space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GF(2)), which means that `-1 = 1` and `1 + 1 = 0`.

I already have a working `backSubstitute()` method:

```
def backSubstitute(toggle, puzzle):
    # toggle (matrix) and puzzle (vector) in reduced row echelon form
    # Initialize result vector
    result = [0] * len(puzzle)
    pivot = -1

    # Iterate from the bottom up
    for row in xrange(len(puzzle) - 1, -1, -1):

        # Find pivot
        for col in xrange(len(puzzle)):
            if toggle[row][col]:
                pivot = col
                break

        if pivot == -1:
            if puzzle[row]:
                raise RuntimeError("Puzzle has no solution")
        else:
            # iterate across the rest of the row, XORing the values
            # together with the puzzle value and then store the result.
            result[row] = puzzle[row]
            for col in xrange(pivot + 1, len(puzzle)):
                result[row] ^= toggle[row][col] and result[col]

    return result
```

It that returns *one* specific valid solution (`[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]`), but I know there are three different solutions:

- `[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]`
- `[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]`
- `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]`

I'm only interested in the solution with the least number of `1`s, so for this example the desired solution is `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]`.

*This needs to be done in pure python (although solutions in other languages would certainly help me too) without third-party libraries, so **no numpy or sage**.*

[Working example](http://ideone.com/gmANgP)

---

For anyone interested in the rationale behind this problem, it's a "[lights out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lights_Out_(game))" variant solver inspired by [this excellent resource](http://www.keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=lights-out).

Comment: have you looked at the `.count()` method for lists?

Comment: @user2097159 sure, but `backSubstitute()` does not return a list of results and never works with one, which is the problem.

Comment: So it sounds like `backSubstitute()` needs to be reworked because as of know its only returning 1 possible solution not all of them?

Comment: Am I missing something or `toggle` isn't really in row echelon form? The last row is wrong.

Comment: @user2097159 yes, but I don't know where exactly we decide on one solution and can store different results in a list.

Comment: @JuanLopes yes, you're right. One row too many, I edited my question.

Comment: How did you come up with those other 2 answers?

Comment: Manually, since I know the problem I'm trying to solve. I mentioned it in the last paragraph.

Comment: Alright so after a bit of digging I'm not sure your `backSubstitute()` is as accurate as you might like.  To get your optimal solution `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]` at some point we would have to set `result[8] = 1`  the only time we do anything with `result` is `result[row]`  by this logic `row` would have to equal 8.  `row` is equal to 8 only under the first iteration of `for row in xrange(len(puzzle) - 1, -1, -1):` at which no point is there a `1` for `if toggle[row][col]:` to be true.

Comment: I assume this is why it only can generate one solution. Do you have an idea what I'd need to change?

Comment: @user2097159 It seems to be that [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra)#Computation_by_Gaussian_elimination) is what I'm looking for, but I neither can find any algorithm nor understand the math